# How to Display Product Variable prices on product category page in woo commerce?

Tags: woocommerce

How to Display Product Variable prices like weight - 200 grams , 500 grams in product category page in woo commerce ?

Answer (score 1):

File location - **theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php**

and replace the following code

```html
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'woo_display_variation_dropdown_on_shop_page' );
 
 function woo_display_variation_dropdown_on_shop_page() {
     
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
    
    $attribute_keys = array_keys( $product->get_attributes() );
    ?>
    
    
    <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $product->get_available_variations() ) ) ?>">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>
    
        <?php if ( empty( $product->get_available_variations() ) && false !== $product->get_available_variations() ) : ?>
            <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
            <?php else : ?>
                <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ( $product->get_attributes() as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                                <td class="value">
                    <?php
                    
                        $attribute_data = $options->get_data();
                        //echo '+++++'.$attribute_name.'++++++'; echo '<pre>'; print_r($attribute_data); exit();
                    
                        $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                        
                        wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( 
                        array( 
                        'options' => $attribute_data['options'], 
                        'attribute' => $attribute_name, 
                        'product' => $product, 
                        'selected' => $selected ));
                        
                        echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                        
                    ?>
                    
                <?php
                    /*wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                        array(
                            'options'   => $options,
                            'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                            'product'   => $product,
                        )
                    );
                    echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';*/
                ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    
            <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_before_single_variation Hook.
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );
    
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_single_variation hook. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                     * @since 2.4.0
                     * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                     * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );
    
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_after_single_variation Hook.
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
                ?>
            </div>
    
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
    </form>

        
    <?php } else {
        
    echo sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    
    }
     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**theme->woocommerce->content-product.php**

```html
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()))
{
    echo woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
}
```